# Avoiding code duplication when the only difference is loop control statements (with the same statements in loop bodies)?

Tags: c++, algorithm, design-patterns, code-duplication

In my solution code for [project euler problem 11](http://projecteuler.net/problem=11), I got the following functions. `Max_consecutive_prod` is a class which calculates the max product of consecutive `input()`ed numbers, generalised from [problem 8](http://projecteuler.net/problem=8). The six functions calculate max product in different series of different directions and start from different edges of the grid.

The only difference in these functions is indexes in `for` statements, how to elimilate the obvious duplication? The situation here is somehow the opposite to the typical application of `template method` pattern: the operation is identical but the control framework is different, is there another design pattern for this?

Edit: all the modifications specified in comments are to the (two) `for` statements, and the loop body in each function is identical to the first.

```
template <size_t size> unsigned process_row(const unsigned (&grid)[size][size])
{
    unsigned prodMax = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    {
        Max_consecutive_prod mcp;
        for (int j = 0; j < size; ++j)
        {
            mcp.input(grid[i][j]);
        }
        if (mcp.result() > prodMax)
        {
            prodMax = mcp.result();
        }
    }
    return prodMax;
}
// exchange i, j in process_row
template <size_t size> unsigned process_col(const unsigned (&grid)[size][size])
{
    // ...
}

template <size_t size> unsigned process_diag_lower(const unsigned (&grid)[size][size])
{
    unsigned prodMax = 0;
    for (int init = 0; init < size; ++init)
    {
        Max_consecutive_prod mcp;
        for (int i = init, j = 0; i < size && j < size; ++i, ++j)
            // ...
        // ...
    }
    return prodMax;
}
// exchange i, j in process_diag_lower
template <size_t size> unsigned process_diag_upper(const unsigned (&grid)[size][size])
{
    // ...
}
// flip j in process_diag_lower
template <size_t size> unsigned process_rev_diag_lower(const unsigned (&grid)[size][size])
{
    unsigned prodMax = 0;
    for (int init = 0; init < size; ++init)
    {
        Max_consecutive_prod mcp;
        for (int i = init, j = size-1; i < size && j >= 0; ++i, --j)
            // ...
        // ...
    }
    return prodMax;
}
// change ++j in process_diag_upper to --j
template <size_t size> unsigned process_rev_diag_upper(const unsigned (&grid)[size][size])
{
    unsigned prodMax = 0;
    for (int init = 0; init < size; ++init)
    {
        Max_consecutive_prod mcp;
        for (int j = init, i = 0; j >=0 && i < size; ++i, --j)
            // ...
        // ...
    }
    return prodMax;
}
```

Based on random-hacker's code, which shows the real commonality and variability in control flows of the six function, I wrote my version and made the code more self-explaining and C++ idiomatic, using a `stragegy` class, defining local variables to clarify the code and improve effiency. I define a non-template version of `process()`, to avoid binary code bloat when instantizing for different `size` (see 'Effective C++', Item 44).

If you still get confused, please read random-hacker's answer for explanation. :)

```
namespace Grid_search
{
    enum Step { neg = -1, nul, pos };
    enum Index_t { i, j };

    struct Strategy
    {
        Step direction[2];
        Index_t varOuter;
    };

    const size_t typeCount = 6;
    const Strategy strategy[typeCount] = { {{pos, nul}, i}, {{nul, pos}, j}, {{pos, pos}, i}, {{pos, pos}, j}, {{pos, neg}, i}, {{pos, neg}, j} };
};

template <size_t size> inline unsigned process(const Grid_search::Strategy& strategy, const unsigned (&grid)[size][size])
{
    return process(strategy, reinterpret_cast<const unsigned*>(&grid), size);
}

unsigned process(const Grid_search::Strategy& strategy, const unsigned* grid, size_t size)
{
    using namespace Grid_search;

    const Index_t varOuter = strategy.varOuter, varInner = static_cast<Index_t>(!varOuter);
    const Step di = strategy.direction[i], dj = strategy.direction[j];
    const unsigned initInner = strategy.direction[varInner] == pos ? 0 : size -1;

    unsigned prodMax = 0;
    unsigned index[2];
    unsigned &indexI = index[i], &indexJ = index[j];
    for (unsigned initOuter = 0; initOuter < size; ++initOuter)
    {
        Max_consecutive_prod mcp;
        for (index[varOuter] = initOuter, index[varInner] = initInner;
            0 <= indexI && indexI < size && 0 <= indexJ && indexJ < size;
            indexI += di, indexJ += dj)
        {
            mcp.input(grid[indexI*size + indexJ]);
            if (mcp.result() > prodMax)
            {
                prodMax = mcp.result();
            }
        }
    }
    return prodMax;
}


int main()
{
    static const size_t N = 20;
    unsigned grid[N][N];

    std::ifstream input("d:/pro11.txt");
    for (int count = 0; input >> grid[count/N][count%N]; ++count)
    {
    }

    unsigned prodMax = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < Grid_search::typeCount; ++i)
    {
        unsigned prod = process(Grid_search::strategy[i], grid);
        if (prod > prodMax)
        {
            prodMax = prod;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Would a simple function work?

Comment: Please show the bodies of the functions which you commented out, because when you say *"exchange i, j . . ."* -- It's not clear exactly at which points in the function they should be exchanged.  Obviously it's not *every* point, otherwise the functions are identical, and there is no need to write them both.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley all the points in the loop statements but not in the loop bodies, the loop body in each of the functions is the same as the first.

Comment: As Adam asks - why can't you just create/call a function ala `template <size_t size> void ij_loop(int i, int j, Max_consecutive_prod& mcp, const unsigned (&grid)[size][size])` for the inside loop, and another similar function for whatever common code's after that loop but still inside the outer loop?

Comment: @TonyD yeah, it works and makes the code looks better. But I think it just hides but not solves the problem. For example: how about the code changed and made the parameter list of the functions to be created so long that even more annoying than just leaving the duplication there? (`(int i, int j, Max_consecutive_prod& mcp, const unsigned (&grid)[size][size])` already discomforts me a little..); how about the control flow was very complex (but still much the same in each function) and made it impossible to extract just several functions?

Comment: @TonyD And at the very least, we still need to write nearly the same function six times.. @_@

Comment: @wpzdm: there's definitely a threshold for duplication vs. factoring - experience will inform where you draw that line.  There are numerous ways to simplify things: packing the relevant data context into a single object that can be easily passed to `ij_loop`, using a Policy template to control the iteration, adopting some Iterator or Visitor pattern - you don't show us enough loop bodies to see the common requirements....

Comment: @TonyD Can you kindly show an example of one of the patterns you mentioned, by applying them to the above code?

Comment: @wpzdm: see answer below, which illustates a Context and a Visitor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I think what you already have will be fine after sticking the inner loop code blocks in an ordinary function as suggested by Adam Burry and Tony D, if you want you can combine the loops, using tables to encode the possible directions to move in.  The trick is to use an array `p[2]` instead of separate `i` and `j`, to enable the question of *which index is varied in the outer loop* to be driven by a table.  Then the only tricky thing is making sure that the other index, which will be varied in the inner loop, needs to start at its maximum value (instead of 0) iff it will decrement at each step:

```
enum indices { I, J };       // Can just use 0 and 1 if you want
template <size_t size> unsigned process(const unsigned (&grid)[size][size]) {
    static int d[][2] = { {1, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 1}, {1, -1}, {1, 1}, {1, -1} };
    static int w[]    = {      J,      I,      J,       J,      I,       I };
    unsigned prodMax = 0;    // Note: not 1
    for (int k = 0; k < sizeof d / sizeof d[0]; ++k) {  // For each direction
        for (int init = 0; init < size; ++init) {
            Max_consecutive_prod mcp;
            int p[2];        // p[I] is like i, p[J] is like j
            for (p[w[k]] = init, p[!w[k]] = (d[k][!w[k]] == -1 ? size - 1 : 0);
                 min(p[I], p[J]) >= 0 && max(p[I], p[J]) < size;
                 p[I] += d[k][I], p[J] += d[k][J])
            {
                mcp.input(grid[p[I]][p[J]]);
                prodMax = max(prodMax, mcp.result());
            }
        }
    }

    return prodMax;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create an enum for the different states and then pass it into the function. You would then create an if statement that would set the values based on the passed value.

Comment: hmm.. simple change to the initial state of loop statements will not do, even if it would, it's, imho, not elegant.

Answer (score 0):

Your `process_row()` has a bug: from the example in the link, zero entries are allowed in the matrix, so if a row begins with e.g.

```
x y z 0 ...
```

and any of x, xy or xyz is larger than all other 4-element products on the rest of that row and on any other row in the matrix, it will incorrectly report that the this is the largest 4-element product.  (I'm assuming here that `Max_consecutive_prod` calculates a rolling product of the last 4 elements provided with `input()`).

Unless your `Max_consecutive_prod` is unusually aware of how it is being called, you will also get erroneous results "wrapping" from the end of one row to the next, and from one `process_...()` call to the next.

Comment: NVM, my Max_consecutive_prod copes with all these, let's focus on the duplication. :)

Comment: So it knows to flush itself after each row, and after each method, by counting the number of times `input()` has been called?  That's definitely an unusually highly-coupled way to program it...

Comment: @j-random-hacker No. note that a new a Max_consecutive_prod object is created for each outer loop...

Comment: `unsigned prodMax = 1;` is a bug though.  You need to be setting this to zero, in case every element in the matrix is 0.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you flattened the grid so that it was just 400 numbers in a row, reading left to right and then top to bottom. The topmost row would consist of the first 20 numbers (that is, indices 0, ..., 19); the second rwo of the next 20 numbers, etc. In general, row `i` (starting from 0) would correspond to indices `i*20, i*20 + 1, i*20 + 2, ..., i*20 + 19`.

Now, what about columns? The leftmost column starts at position 0, just like the topmost row. It's next element at position 20 (the first element in the second row), and then 40, and... So it's not hard to see that the indices for column `j` are `j, j + 20, j + 40, ..., j + 19*20`.

Diagonals are not much different. Try it on paper (grid-ruled paper is good for this sort of thing.)

One more hint: Does it make a difference if you find the product of four elements, multiplying left-to-right, than the same four elements multiplying right-to-left?

Comment: Er... I noted these facts, how can I use them to elimilate the duplication?

Comment: @wpzdm: I thought you'd enjoy working it out. Why else would you be doing Project Euler? ... But if you insist: every type of iteration can be represented as a starting point and an offset, so that the iteration is start, start+offset, start+2*offset,... You have to watch out for diagonals because they are mostly shorter, so that's actually three parameters.

Comment: Your method will produce different control flow from mine, with the same amount of duplicated code. And even the control flow is in essence same, with only translation from matrix index to array index.

Answer (score 0):

First, the Context object approach - this just packages the arguments to the support functions mentioned in my comment on your question... it's about as useful as the problem was significant ;-].

```
struct Context
{
    unsigned& proxMax;
    int i, j;
    Max_consecutive_prod mcp;
    Context(unsigned& prodMax) : prodMax(prodMax) { }
};

template <size_t size> unsigned process_diag_lower(const unsigned (&grid)[size][size])
{
    unsigned prodMax = 0;
    for (int init = 0; init < size; ++init)
    {
        Context context(prodMax);
        for (context.i = init, context.j = 0; context.i < size && context.j < size; ++context.i, ++context.j)
            loop_ij(context);
        loop_outer(context);
    }
    return prodMax;
}
```

---

Visitor pattern.  Now, I said in my comment "you don't show us enough loop bodies to see the common requirements", and haven't seen anything since, so on the basis of the one body I've seen - namely:

```
template <size_t size> unsigned process_row(const unsigned (&grid)[size][size])
{
    unsigned prodMax = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    {
        Max_consecutive_prod mcp;
        for (int j = 0; j < size; ++j)
        {
            mcp.input(grid[i][j]);
        }
        if (mcp.result() > prodMax)
        {
            prodMax = mcp.result();
        }
    }
    return prodMax;
}
```

The above can be split:

```
template <size_t size, template Visitor>
unsigned visit_row(const unsigned (&grid)[size][size], Visitor& visitor)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < size; ++j)
            visitor.inner{grid[i][j]);
        visitor.outer();
    }
    return visitor.result();
}

struct Visitor
{
    unsigned prodMax;
    Max_consecutive_prod mcp;
    Visitor() : prodMax(0) { }
    void inner(unsigned n) {  mcp.input(n); }
    void outer()
    {
        if (mcp.result() > prodMax) prodMax = mcp.result();
        mcp = Max_consecutive_prod();  // reset for next time...
    }
    unsigned result() const { return prodMax; }
};
```

This way, the same Visitor class can be combined with your various grid-element iteration routines.

Comment: thx! Both approaches are general, but still require writing six functions :(

Comment: @wpzdm: the issue is whether there's enough commonality in the functions to be worth factoring... there's nothing to stop you writing one function, then passing it some guiding data about the order and direction to increment each of the loops in... if you try that and can't get it to work as expected, post code and I'll help.